# Convert object from tree format to array format

Tags: javascript

I have an object, I need to parse and put in another object from format 1 to format 2.

Format 1:

```
let mydata=[{
    "_children": {
        "5": {
            "_children": {
                "7": {
                    "_children": {},
                    "id": "7",
                    "name": "subject11",
                    "parentID": 5
                },
                "10": {
                    "_children": {},
                    "id": "10",
                    "name": "subject12",
                    "parentID": 5
                }
            },
            "id": "5",
            "name": "subject1",
            "parentID": null
        },
        "6": {
            "_children": {
                "8": {
                    "_children": {},
                    "id": "8",
                    "name": "subject21",
                    "parentID": 6
                },
                "9": {
                    "_children": {},
                    "id": "9",
                    "name": "subject22",
                    "parentID": 6
                }
            },
            "id": "6",
            "name": "subject2",
            "parentID": null
        }
    }
}]
```

Format 2:

```
let endresult=[
    {"id":7,    "name":"subject11",   "parent":"subject1"},
    {"id":10,   "name":"subject12",   "parent":"subject1"}
    {"id":8,    "name":"subject21",   "parent":"subject2"},
    {"id":9,    "name":"subject22",   "parent":"subject2"},  
]
```

Do you have any idea?

Comment: `I have a json object` no you don't you have a regular old array.

Comment: Do _you_ have any idea? What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: why is not `id = 6` in the result set? why is the given data an array?

Answer (score 0):

tldr:

```js
let mydata = [{
  "_children": {
      "5": {
          "_children": {
              "7": {
                  "_children": {},
                  "id": "7",
                  "name": "subject11",
                  "parentID": 5
              },
              "10": {
                  "_children": {},
                  "id": "10",
                  "name": "subject12",
                  "parentID": 5
              }
          },
          "id": "5",
          "name": "subject1",
          "parentID": null
      },
      "6": {
          "_children": {
              "8": {
                  "_children": {},
                  "id": "8",
                  "name": "subject21",
                  "parentID": 6
              },
              "9": {
                  "_children": {},
                  "id": "9",
                  "name": "subject22",
                  "parentID": 6
              }
          },
          "id": "6",
          "name": "subject2",
          "parentID": null
      }
  }
}]

const convertFormat = (data, parentName = null) => {
  let result = [];
  for (let key in data._children) {
    let item = data._children[key];
    if (Object.keys(item._children).length > 0) {
      result = result.concat(convertFormat(item, item.name));
    }
    if (item.parentID !== null) {
      result.push({ id: parseInt(item.id), name: item.name, parent: parentName });
    }
  }
  return result;
}

let endresult = convertFormat(mydata[0]);
console.log(endresult);
// [
//   {"id":7,    "name":"subject11",   "parent":"subject1"},
//   {"id":10,   "name":"subject12",   "parent":"subject1"},
//   {"id":8,    "name":"subject21",   "parent":"subject2"},
//   {"id":9,    "name":"subject22",   "parent":"subject2"},
// ]
```

Answer (score -1):

You could get the entries and a flat array as result.

```js
const
    data = { _children: { 5: { _children: { 7: { _children: {}, id: "7", name: "subject11", parentID: 5 }, 10: { _children: {}, id: "10", name: "subject12", parentID: 5 } }, id: "5", name: "subject1", parentID: null }, 6: { _children: { 8: { _children: {}, id: "8", name: "subject21", parentID: 6 }, 9: { _children: {}, id: "9", name: "subject22", parentID: 6 } }, id: "6", name: "subject2", parentID: null } } },
    flat = object => Object
        .values(object)
        .flatMap(({ _children, ...node }) => [
            ...(node.parentID === null ? [] : [node]),
            ...(_children ? flat(_children) : [])
        ]),
    result = flat(data._children);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```